# Merge request from different branches, do I need to merge master to them too?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-request

using gitlab, I have multiple developing branches.
An example:

- dev A working on branch deva
- dev B working on branch devb

Both of them ask for a merge request. So for example deva will be merged on master. But now in devb there are not the last changes.

My question is, after every MR, do I need to merge master to the other branches too?

I hope I explained myself well.
Thanks

Comment: "ask for a merge request" -- you mean "request a merge"? In any case, that should be covered by any git tutorial that deals with feature branches. Short answer, maybe, but maybe you want to rebase instead.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is no need to always merge the master into your feature branch. Only if you depend on the changes the other branch has made. In the best case, development is organized in such a way that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to merge the master to branchB when you will merge this one. You can do it right after or in a month.
Furthermore, you just need your branch to be up-to-date with the master before doing an MR (or PR pull request).

Comment: It is not necessary that a branch is up-to-date with the master branch before merging as long as there are no merge conflicts.